# iterating through elements in unordered map of unordered_maps cpp

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Suppose I have an unordered_map defined as below:

```
unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>> f_table;
f_table[1][3] = 10;
f_table[1][2] = 1;
f_table[1][1] = 2;
f_table[2][3] = 11;
f_table[2][2] = 22;
f_table[2][1] = 4;
f_table[3][3] = 1;
f_table[3][2] = 3;
f_table[3][1] = 2;
```

And I wanted to sum up all elements in f_table[1] which should add up to 13. How would I go about it?

Comment: An unordererd map seems like the wrong tool here. Why not use `std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>` and zero-index?

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over any other container? Do you know what the *value type* of a [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)? When you know that it should become easy.

Comment: Because I dont know how large it will get.

Comment: sum = 0, for(auto& pair : f_table[1]) sum += pair.second; you might want to check if f_table[1] exists first.

Comment: How about using *vectors* then? Or will the "indexes" ever be non-consecutive?

Comment: yes. the indices would be non-consecutive in some cases.

Comment: What about if I wanted to sum up the elements with a second key of 3 ie. f[?][3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int32_t sum = 0;
for (auto& p : f_table[1])
{
    sum += p.second
}
```

Answer (score 7):

One approach is using `std::accumulate` like this:

```
#include <numeric>

const int result = std::accumulate(f_table[1].cbegin(), f_table[1].cend(),
    0, [](int result, const auto& entry){ return result + entry.second; });
```

Note that as @StoryTeller pointed out in the comments, you might want to prefer a parallel version of this algorithm, which will ship with fully conforming C++17 implementations, i.e., [`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce).

Another option is a range based for loop. With structured bindings (again available in C++17), you might consider this more readable:

```
int result = 0;

for (const auto& [key, value] : f_table[1])
   result += value;
```

And finally a solution based on [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/):

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

using ranges::view::values;
using ranges::accumulate;

const int result = accumulate(f_table[1] | values, 0);
```

Comment: If we mention C++17, then `std::accumulate` can be substituted for the paralleled version of `std::reduce`

Comment: That's a good idea, but is it available? Doesn't seem to be supported according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Comment: Doesn't matter. Answers are not only for the benefit of the OP *now*, but for future readers too.

Comment: Well, it does matter, if the solution doesn't work. There may be _some_ value if it could work in 10 years' time but then post it in 10 years time